# Mesos masters behind load balancer

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I have 3 Mesos masters running and all are registers with Zookeepers.

**3 Mesos URL :-**

1. http://mesos1.test.com:5050
2. http://mesos2.test.com:5050
3. http://mesos3.test.com:5050

Now, All 3 URLs can be accessed from my local browser. So, When I hit the 1st URL, it will redirect me to the leader URL if it is not the leader.

Now, I am trying to setup load balancer on top of this. So the load balancer URL will be

> http://mesos.test.com:5050

This will route requests to the backend nodes.

Now, I am trying to set ACLs so that the node URLs can not be accessed directly and only the Load Balancer URL can be accessed.

Here, the problem is when I try to hit the load balancer URL, it sends requests to one of the node and it asks browser to reload the master URL which is actually the direct node URl which is restricted. Is there anyway to get rid of this with Mesos config?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `--advertise_ip` and `--hostname`. Set `hostname` to `mesos.test.com` and `advertise_ip` to proper host IP.

Source: http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/master-and-agent/